# AudioUnits and MPMusicPlayerController

Tags: iphone, audio, audiounit, mpmusicplayercontroller

My App is utilizing the `AudioUnit` functionality to produce short sounds for a metronome application.
All is running fine.

Now I want to play an MP3 from the iTunes Lib on the Device and I use `MPMusicPlayerController` for it.

No probs until here, the MP3 plays fine. But afterwards I can never again invoke my `AudioUnit` sounds again. I debugged it that far that the callback for the Audio buffers never ever appears again so I think the `AUGraph` has been stopped but it signals that it is still running.

Anyone having an idea? Did the `MPMusicPlayerController` just stop the Graph? And how to prevent that?

Thanks for any hint,
Andreas

Answer (score 2):

From this [doc](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/Audio/Conceptual/AudioSessionProgrammingGuide/WorkingWithOpenALiPodMusicandMovies/WorkingWithOpenALiPodMusicandMovies.html), *"Music players (instances of the MPMusicPlayerController class) always use a system-supplied audio session."* Your application can't access system-supplied audio sessions as far as I know. Therefore, it's not possible for MPMusicPlayerController audio and your app audio to be played simultaneously.

In order to play an MP3 from the iPod library and your metronome simultaneously, do the following:

1. Set up an AUGraph with its own audio session
2. Read the MP3's samples with AVAssetReader
3. Feed samples to your AUGraph on one channel
4. Mix in metronome audio on the other channel